# Manually release app on AppStore after Apple approved it

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

Is there a possibility to manually release app when it has been approved by Apple, so that I can do it at any time after the approval?

Comment: Yes, you can select the release mode for your app in iTunesConnect

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use these checkboxes on your app page itunesconnect to manage your release time:

[image]